# Is it acceptable to ask for software recommendations?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm searching for an Online Password Manager to move all my passwords to, and I'd like to ask to the community their choices and preferences. Is it acceptable to ask for the "top" Password Managers, or the most used by the community?

Thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, this is specifically not allowed in the FAQ. Your proposed question is also highly opinion-based.

There is a [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) stack. Be sure to read their [question guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information). You can't just ask “what's the best online password manager” since that would be highly opinion-based. Explain clearly what you're looking for so that people can recommend something that's suited to your particular needs.

Comment: [Searching](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=recommendations) doesn't turn up anything, seems like it should be added to [on-topic](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or [dont-ask](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @AndrolGenhald - "Opinion-based" is mentioned, and Stack Exchange as a whole has the no shopping recommendations requirement (except as mentioned above)

Answer (score 4):

As @schroeder says, this is not allowed and is opinion-based.

However, what you can do instead is ask for *criteria* that should be considered when choosing such a product, and how to compare.
For example, [this question I asked several years ago](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36664/33).

This is not subjective, nor does it have the other problems that product recommendation questions typically have. It is also unlikely to change very quickly.
[Here is another example; I still refer to the answers here 7 years later, still completely up to date.](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/7326/33).